# preg_match php returning text between two search paramaters

Tags: php, preg-match

if this is a duplicate I apologise but i couldnt find anything on google after hours of searching, im pretty new to string manipulation and dont really know the correct terminology to find the information i want.

Basically I am manipulating this string

```
        Date       Time      Name             IP                 UniqueID
$line = 02.12.2013 16:00:03: Connor Bergolio (75.13.15.229:5557) fcfd6ba862c7461a88e2b13babc691dd
```

So I am trying to retreive the name, However as they can choose whatever name they want, it could have 1 space or 10 spaces so explode is out of the question.

Now I was wondering if it is possible to run a pregmatch using 2 variables. that will return the information between

```
$pattern1 = '$time, $ip';
preg_match($pattern1, $line, $name);
```

Looking at that, its way off, but I'm pretty much at a loss

Im using `$IPpattern = '/([0-9-():.)]{19,23})/'; 
to get the IP maybe using that and a search for time together?

Thanks in advance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this regex to retrieve the name:

```
 /[\d{2}.]{2}\d{4}\s(\d{2}:){3}\s(.+)(\s\(.+)/
```

[Have a play](http://regex101.com/r/lY6oE9), the second result from this is your name.

Comment: Thank you so much for that tool, it looks very intresteing and i will be able to use it well to help with future features. it was very hard to choose from, but due to the tool. I have to pick this :) Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

The following pattern will work:

```
preg_match('/^(.{19}): (.+?) +\(([0-9:.]+)\) ([a-f0-9]+)$/', $line, $matches);
$date = $matches[1];
$name = $matches[2];
$ip = $matches[3];
$uniqueId = $matches[4];
```

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing the vaild characters allowed for a username, or any of the rules governing the format of `Date` and `Time` fields, the following should work:

```
.*(?:\d\d:){3}\s*\K.+(?=\s?\()
```

### EXPLAINED

`.*(?:\d\d:){3}\s*\K` - Match everything up to `Time` field then drop it with `\K`

`.+(?=\s?\()` - Match anything one or more times up to but not including the first bracket found

It's not efficient though :(